# access other groups/hosts ip in Ansible task

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to allow connections from certain hosts/group to a server using ufw 
module 
this is my inventory file

```
[web]
foo.domain
bar.domain
[db]
foo.anotherdomain
[production:children]
web
db
```

and here is my playbook

```
- name: gather all hosts facts
  user: root
  hosts: all

- name : allow access from web group  to database
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    src: "{{ hostvars['web']['ansible_default_ipv4'].address }}"
    port: 5432
    comment: allow postgres from web
```

but i get this error

```
fatal: [142.93.128.240]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['web}}']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/reza/labs/testtask.yml': line 10, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - debug: msg=\"{{hostvars['web}}']['ansible_default_ipv4'].address}}\"\n      ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
```

how can i loop through all members of a group or a single host and pick a variable value (in this case host ip) ?

Comment: Besides not gathering the facts as suggested in the dup-target, your error message contains something that is not in your code `\"hostvars['web}}']\"`.